# Using Win32 Crypto API

Tags: winapi, cryptography, aescryptoserviceprovider

I can't find any help to implement PROV_RSA_AES CSP in c++. is there any article or book to help me out with it?

Comment: Do you actually want to implement a CSP? Or do you just want to use one?

Comment: i just want to use one, i figured how to get context but i'm still thinking about the size of buffer i need to use for CryptEncrypt() to get it working with aes256 ? i also want to use random salt.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.ddj.com/windows/184416931) is an article about it.
[Here](http://www.ddj.com/windows/184416394) is another one.

Comment: i can't find the first part of this article.

Comment: the other one uses PROV_RSA_FULL.

Comment: You should be able to figure out the rest with those two articles.

Answer (score 0):

> i just want to use one, i figured
>   how to get context but i'm still
>   thinking about the size of buffer i
>   need to use for CryptEncrypt() to get
>   it working with aes256 ? i also want
>   to use random salt.

AES256 in CBC-mode with PKCS#7-padding (which is the default) will need a buffersize that is the input-data rounded up to the next multiple of 16 (but always at least one byte more). Ie. 35 -> 48, 52 -> 64, 80 -> 96.

There is no salt involved in AES256. Are you talking about key-derivation? Or do you mean the IV?